# Sending email in J2EE

Tags: jakarta-ee

in my website, I want to send a email to a user when he creates an account (for example), in this case the part of the code that is responsible for this should be in a servlet or in a ejb?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doesn't matter: if you are sending an email, just configure email resource configuration for your mail server, then use JNDI or CDI to look up the mail session, create and send email message. But since sending emails could be slow, good architectural practice is sometimes to decouple it from the rest of the application, e.g. by sending email into JMS queue and use a separate message-driven EJB that will do the actual sending.